# ¿Cómo entro a una carpeta u obtengo el id de una carpeta creada?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Estoy creando un script con google, e intento crear una carpeta y posteriormente en esa carpeta creada pegar una hoja de sheets, todo con google script, pero no logro hacerlo. Mi idea es que al momento de crear la carpeta, pueda obtener el id de esa carpeta creada para posteriormente pegar el archivo dentro de esa carpeta. He intentado de todo pero no logro hacerlo. Hasta el momento mi código es el siguiente:

```
function crearCarpetaPath(){
  var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
  var pathIndex = "ruta";
  var path = DriveApp.getFolderById(pathIndex);
  path.createFolder(actualSheetName + " 14");
```

La siguiente linea de código me sirve para obtener el ID de la carpeta donde me encuentro, pero lo que quiero es digamos entrar a la carpeta creada y obtener ese ID

```
var id = path.getId();
```

Intenté también con la siguiente linea de código pero tampoco:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pathIndex).getFoldersByName(actualSheetName)
```

Espero me puedan apoyar! muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reemplaza

```
path.createFolder(actualSheetName + " 14");
```

por

```
var carpetaCreada = path.createFolder(actualSheetName + " 14");
```

Para obtener el `id` de la carpeta creada, en lugar de

```
var id = path.getId();
```

usa

```
var id = carpetaCreada.getId();
```